# How to add time in minutes in datetime string?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in Codeigniter project and I want to add time in minutes in datetime string.
I have a datetime string,

```
2020-09-25 12:20:00
```

and I want to add time

```
10 minutes
```

Comment: where is `10 minuts` in `2020-09-25 12:20:00`?

Comment: in date-time string 12:20:00, 20 are minutes and I want to add 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newtimestamp = strtotime('2020-09-25 12:20:00 + 10 minute');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newtimestamp);
```

**Output:-**

2020-09-25 12:30:00